# Check if a class has a pointer data member

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, sfinae

Is there a way to test if a class has a pointer data member?

```
class Test
{
  int* p;
}

template< typename T >
foo( T bla )
{
}
```

This should not compile. because Test has a pointer data member.

```
Test test;
foo( test )
```

Maybe I can use a trait to disable the template? Or is my only option macros? Maybe someone knows if boost can do it?

Comment: You need declare return type for foo().

Comment: http://www.gockelhut.com/c++/articles/has_member

Comment: What do you really want to do in your template function? How it associated with pointer in class?

Comment: Why this shouldn't compile?

Comment: "Check if a class has a pointer data member" - why? I don't see why a pointer would make a difference.

Comment: @Ahmed because of the missing semicolon :) Seriously, he's trying to say "I want to static assert that the class has no pointer member"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following can work as a protection, but the member variable has to be accessible (`public`), otherwise it won't work:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Test
{
public:
  int* p;
};

template< typename T >
typename std::enable_if< std::is_pointer< decltype( T::p ) >::value >::type
foo( T bla ) { static_assert( sizeof( T ) == 0, "T::p is a pointer" ); }

template< typename T >
void foo( T bla )
{
}

int main()
{
    Test test;
    foo( test );
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49e53748feb7020d)

Of course you need to know the name of the member variable to check, as there is no general reflection mechanism built into C++.

---

Another way which avoid the ambiguity is to create a `has_pointer` helper:

```
template< typename, typename = void >
struct has_pointer : std::false_type {};

template< typename T >
struct has_pointer< T, typename std::enable_if<
                         std::is_pointer< decltype( T::p ) >::value
                       >::type > : std::true_type {};

template< typename T >
void foo( T bla )
{
    static_assert( !has_pointer< T >::value, "T::p is a pointer" );
    // ...
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39c5439e881a38b8)

Note that I simply added a `static_assert` as the first line to the function to get a nice, readable error message. You could, of course, also disable the function itself with something like this:

```
template< typename T >
typename std::enable_if< !has_pointer< T >::value >::type
foo( T bla )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should remove the ambiguity from the call to `foo`.

Comment: @dyp Updated the answer, showing two ways to improve the error/overlead situation.

Comment: Of course, this assumes there'll be one member only, and it's name shall be p.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to know if there is a way to check for a pointer data member of which we do not know the name. I gave p as an example but the idea is that I do not know what the name will be or if there is only 1 pointer data member. (Same as what @sehe mentioned)

Comment: @user985611 As I already wrote in the answer, you do have to know the name as C++ has no general reflection mechanism. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if there is a way to check for a pointer data member of which we do not know the name. I gave p as an example but the idea is that I do not know what the name will be or if there is only 1 pointer data member

I don't think you can.

You could use gcc's -Weffc++ which will warn about classes with pointer members (that don't have the minimum special members defined).

What I really think you're after, though, is "Does this class have value semantics" ("Do I need to deep clone this"). In C++ you have to **assume this unless copying/assignment are prohibited**.