# Check if a class has >=1 pointer field member (unidentified name)

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++14

How to detect whether a class T has at least 1 member that are pointers?

```
#include <iostream>
class B{
    int k;             //no pointer  -> false
};
class C{
    void* x;           //pointer     -> true
};
class D{
    int someRandom;
    C* aBadPractice;   //pointer     -> true
};
template<class T> bool hasPointer(){  ??
    ???
};
int main(){
    std::cout<<check<B>()<<std::endl; //false
    std::cout<<check<C>()<<std::endl; //true
    std::cout<<check<D>()<<std::endl; //true
}
```

I want to use it to *roughly* check that every type of component in my Entity-Component-System is a *custom* POD (plain old data).

If it is violated, it will alert programmer about potential mistake.

I can't use `std::is_pod` because its criteria is so much different from mine.

**Main objective / criteria :-**

- Can be slow (I don't mind performance).
- Compile-time or Runtime check are both OK.
- It must be non-intrusive.  (`B` `C` & `D` should not be edited)
- If it helps, it is ok to enforce `B` `C` & `D` to inherit from a common class.

**Side objective :-**  (not important)

- can detect private field
- detect inherited field
- detect a field that is a type that has pointer inside it

**Here are similar questions** (they are too different though) :-

- [Check if a class has a member function of a given signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature)  : search function with a  ***specific name***  and signature
- [Check if a class has a pointer data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498421/check-if-a-class-has-a-pointer-data-member) : check whether a field with ***a certain name*** is a pointer.

I personally don't think it is possible.
A solution like "It is impossible" is also a valid answer.

### Edit

My underlying problem is identifying whether I can `memcpy` && omit destructor of them.      I want to relocate them easily and safely - like this : [Can I use memcpy in C++ to copy classes that have no pointers or virtual functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021333/can-i-use-memcpy-in-c-to-copy-classes-that-have-no-pointers-or-virtual-functio).

Now I believe the solution are somethings around `std::is_trivially_destructible` and `std::is_trivially_copyable`.   I will investigate more about them.  I hope they can check whether my class contains any smart pointer.

Thank every comments.

Comment: @user0042   I had put that link and clarified it -  that question is "check whether a field with a ***certain name*** is a pointer."  It is different from mine.

Comment: @Ron I don't think it can be done batch-like though (e.g. `std::is_pointer<C>` is false) .

Comment: This cannot be done in C++. C++ does not work this way. What is the real problem are you trying to solve? No, not the problem of determining if a class a has pointer member, but whatever problem you think the solution is to determine if a class has a pointer member.

Comment: What you're looking for is reflection which looks possible to an extent in c++14, check this talk: https://youtu.be/abdeAew3gmQ

Comment: _I personally don't think it is possible_. It isn't indeed. This smells a lot like an XY-problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_trivially_copyable` is likely the attribute you want. Even if the class contains a pointer, creating a shallow copy can be the right thing. If not, it will have to have a non-trivial copy constructor and/or assignment operator - and thus *not* be trivially copyable.

However, if you just copy or assign an object that *is* trivially copyable the compiler will very likely generate code similar to `memcpy` anyway. There is generally no need to try to optimize this in user code.

Likewise, if there is nothing to destroy the default destructor will be empty and a clear candidate to be removed by the optimizer. For example, consider what happens when an empty destructor is inlined.